# Magento - 2.2.7 City missing on checkout page address section

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have use extension https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown to show city in dropdown but when I enable this extension, city is showing blank in address section of checkout payment page.
[image]

If I tap on "Place order" button then it shows below error:

```
Please check the billing address information. city is a required field
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this file in your theme:

> Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

City Should be remove from there, if yes then please add below code:-

```
<!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->
```

Then File should be look like this:-

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="css: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
    <!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
         <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (address().isEditable()) -->
    <button type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            data-bind="click: editAddress, visible: address().isEditable()">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for show your interest. I have review default.html file and code ok. Problem is accrue when enable City-Dropdown extension .

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite and add the following validations to these js files:

> magento/vendor/eadesignro/romcity/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js:15

```
if (shippingCityIdValue.length) {
    shippingAddress.city = shippingCityIdValue;
}
```

> magento/vendor/eadesignro/romcity/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js:62

Replace

```
if (this.isAddressSameAsShipping()) {
    newAddress.city = shippingCityIdValue;
} else if (billingAddressCity) {
    newAddress.city = billingAddressCity.text();
} else {
    newAddress.city = shippingCityIdValue;
}
```

with:

```
if (shippingCityIdValue) {
    newAddress.city = shippingCityIdValue;
}
if (!this.isAddressSameAsShipping() && billingAddressCity && billingAddressCity.text()) {
    newAddress.city = billingAddressCity.text();
}
```

It seems that they try to add the city from the form but the values are not present anymore when you already have an address set.

Comment: https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown/pull/92
Pull request with the changes